# c# using return attribute what it does?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyTest
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test1 t1 = call();
            Console.Out.WriteLine(t1);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        [return: Test2(g = 5)]
        public static Test1 call()
        {
            Test1 t1 = new Test1();
            Test2 t2 = new Test2();
            return t1;

        }
    }



    class Test1 : Attribute
    {

    }

    class Test2 : Attribute
    {
        public int g;
    }
}
```

here the method `call()`, simply returns the `Test1` object, but what is the purpose of setting the return `attrbite` with class `Test2(g = 5)` ?

should something change or happen? but nothing happens...can anybody explain what is going on?

how does it affect to the Test2 object? and where that object should be?

Answer (score 18):

It's just an attribute, like any other - the *usage* of the attribute is up to whatever decides to use it. It's relatively rare to see attributes for `return`, but it's entirely legal, and it's just metadata which can be examined by reflection.

The C# compiler doesn't have any specific knowledge of attributes used for `return` as far as I'm aware, but you could use it for your own sort of code contracts, for example. As a concrete example, some frameworks include a `NotNullAttribute` which is somewhat-incorrectly applied to whole methods:

```
[NotNull] string Foo()
```

... to say that it won't return a null reference. I think this would be more appropriately (although less concisely) written as:

```
[return:NotNull] string Foo()
```

... to emphasize that it's the return value which is non-null, rather than that being an attribute of the overall method.

Comment: I still don't understand what is the practical purpose of this attribute?

Comment: @user3112115, the purpose is to provide hooks to automate certain things.  In this case it would be to enforce the return value from the method can never be null.  It falls into the realm of meta-programming.  So the first paragraph here is correct.  The attribute can be whatever we need it to be.

Comment: Is the `return` attribute honored by built-in code analyzers?

Comment: @mr5: When you say "built-in code analyzers" which do you mean? Roslyn doesn't use a `NotNull` attribute at all, as far as I'm aware. CodeRush, Resharper etc may take notice of it.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm particularly referring to the default tools in Visual Studio in this case. I was looking for these kinds of attributes since I used to be writing the same thing when I was coding in Java with lints. I wish there are more codes written with this attributes.

Comment: @mr5: No, there's nothing like this in "vanilla" .NET. However, C# 8 will have a new feature in terms of "nullable reference types" at which point it you won't need to apply attributes manually etc at all.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but the first time I had seen this was in Azure Function output bindings - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-return-value?tabs=csharp

Answer (score 3):

An attribute on the return affects (or not: see below) the return value rather than the function itself.

However, on their own, attributes *have no effect*. They are used by other code (including the complier) to modify the operation of the system (eg. by providing metadata). Until there is something to read that attribute it is just unused data in the assembly.